# TimeOut Error when connecting a MUSE EEG to raspberry using muselsl

Tags: python, python-3.x, bluetooth, python-asyncio, raspberry-pi3

I'm working on a project to use the MUSE headband with a Raspberry Pi, im using the library "muselsl" to this purpose, the device detection works just fine, but the connection suddenly stops and then it gives the next error:

rasppvr@raspberrypi:~ $ muselsl stream --address 00:55:DA:B3:2A:E5
Connecting to Muse: 00:55:DA:B3:2A:E5...
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/rasppvr/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/bleak/backends/bluezdbus/client.py", line 209, in connect
reply = await self._bus.call(
File "/home/rasppvr/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dbus_fast/aio/message_bus.py", line 399, in call
await future
asyncio.exceptions.CancelledError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/rasppvr/.local/bin/muselsl", line 8, in 
sys.exit(main())
File "/home/rasppvr/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/muselsl/**main**.py", line 57, in main
cli = CLI(args.command)
File "/home/rasppvr/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/muselsl/cli.py", line 9, in **init**
getattr(self, command)()
File "/home/rasppvr/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/muselsl/cli.py", line 106, in stream
stream(args.address, args.backend, args.interface, args.name, args.ppg,
File "/home/rasppvr/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/muselsl/stream.py", line 221, in stream
didConnect = muse.connect()
File "/home/rasppvr/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/muselsl/muse.py", line 84, in connect
self.device = self.adapter.connect(self.address)
File "/home/rasppvr/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/muselsl/backends.py", line 37, in connect
result.connect()
File "/home/rasppvr/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/muselsl/backends.py", line 45, in connect
_wait(self._client.connect())
File "/home/rasppvr/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/muselsl/backends.py", line 11, in _wait
return loop.run_until_complete(coroutine)
File "/usr/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 642, in run_until_complete
return future.result()
File "/home/rasppvr/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/bleak/**init**.py", line 605, in connect
return await self._backend.connect(**kwargs)
File "/home/rasppvr/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/bleak/backends/bluezdbus/client.py", line 310, in connect
raise
File "/home/rasppvr/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/async_timeout/**init**.py", line 141, in **aexit**
self._do_exit(exc_type)
File "/home/rasppvr/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/async_timeout/**init**.py", line 228, in _do_exit
raise asyncio.TimeoutError
asyncio.exceptions.TimeoutError

I've been searching for a couple of days and still don't know how to solve this
I'm very sorry for my broken english

I've tried to use a diferent power source for the raspberry pi, thinking that maybe the problem was caused by a lack of power, but it didn't work, then i tried the different functions to connect:
muselsl stream
muselsl stream --name THENAMEOFTHEMUSE
muselsl stream --address THE ADDRESS OF THE MUSE

This is the repository i'm using for this
https://github.com/alexandrebarachant/muse-lsl

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.